# how to use winmerge line filter for a java comment

Tags: regex, winmerge

how can i filter all the java comments in winmerge?

```
/**
 * javadoc comment
**/

// line comment
```

These are the lines I would like to filter out?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help: (***Winmerge 2.14.0.0 Unicode***)

1. From **Edit** menu, goto **Options**.
2. In the opened window, go to on the categories on the left, select *Compare* then *General*.
3. On the right, you'll see a fieldset named `Comments`. Click the checkbox left to `Filter Comments`.
4. Click **OK**

For more details here is what the [Winmerge documentation](http://manual.winmerge.org/Configuration.html#d0e5947) says about this option:

> 3.8. Filter Comments
> Disabled (default): WinMerge compares comments in code, along with other content.
>
> Enabled: This option optimizes comparisons by detecting comments in certain programming language file types (such as C++ and Java), and ignoring them.
>
> The recognized file types and their comment markers are defined in the file, IgnoreSectionMarkers.ini, at the top of the WinMerge installation directory.

On the other hand, you can filter out the comments only files:

1. **File** > **Open...**
2. From the opened window, set the `Filter:` field as you want. Look below:
   [image: Set filter field from Select Files or Folders window - Winmerge 2.14.0.0 Unicode]

Comment: it does help when i compare two files.. But when I try to compare 2 folders, the files which have only comment differences still show differences..  is there some other way to fix it..

Comment: You can select those files and click `Hide items`

Comment: I have almost 100 files in a folder and want winmerge to highlight the  items that have changes. And I dont want the comment changes to be considered by winnmerge. So they should not be highlighted at all. Hiding them would not be possible until i look into all of them, which actually just makes the above solution of no use for me...

Comment: Can you use the `Filter` option in the *Select Files to Compare* window? Otherwise, I don't have any more solution.

Comment: don't really get it.. what do you mean?